# How to use jq to filter an array with elements of mixed type

Tags: json, jq

Given the below JSON, I'm trying to select all the `command` elements. My issue is that the `"checkout"` string is messing up my selection of all the `"run"` dicts.

I'm trying to pass jq something like `.[].run.command` but I keep getting the error `jq: error (at <stdin>:33): Cannot index string with string "run"`

How do I exclude the `"checkout"` string from being selected?

```
[
  "checkout",
  {
    "run": {
      "command": "pip install cfn-lint pycodestyle pyflakes",
      "name": "Install Dependencies"
    }
  },
  {
    "run": {
      "command": "find stacks -type f -name \"*.yml\" -exec cfn-lint -i E3016 -i E3012 -i E1029 --template {} \\; | tee -a output.txt",
      "name": "Run cfn-lint"
    }
},
  {
    "run": {
      "command": "find stacks -type f -name \"*.py\" -exec pyflakes {} \\; | tee -a output.txt",
      "name": "Run pyflakes"
    }
  },
  {
    "run": {
      "command": "pycodestyle --show-source --show-pep8 --ignore=E501,W605 stacks/src | tee -a output.txt",
      "name": "Run pycodestyle"
    }
  },
  {
    "run": {
      "command": "if [[ -s output.txt ]]; then cat output.txt; exit 1; fi",
      "name": "Exit if there are validation warnings/errors"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that is a simple variation of the filter you've shown:

```
.[].run?.command
```

The "?" is syntactic sugar for a `try` wrapper.

Here's another variation, which suggests still others:

```
.[] | objects | .run.command
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're dealing with  sets of those kinds of arrays with a fixed structure where the first item is like an alias followed by a bunch of actions, you could just skip the first item and process the rest.

```
.[1:][].run.command
```

Otherwise if it is truly mixed and any item can be anything, some sort of filtering would have to be done as peak outlines.